# Google Cloud Text to Speech - Why is there a latency discrepancy between requests through the Go client library and the REST API?

Tags: http, go, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-text-to-speech

My goal is to get the `audioContent` from my call to Google Cloud's Text to Speech in Base64. My current program makes the same exact call twice: once through Google's TTS client library, and the other through an authentication token which I have to HORRIBLY copy and paste from running the command `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`. Obviously, as recommended by Google Cloud, I should be using the client library. The issue, as you can see in the terminal when I time the requests in both methods, is that the client library **takes 4-5 times as long!!!**

```
% go run main.go                                                           
[CLIENT LIBRARY took 586ms]
[REST API took 138ms]
```

The delay is consistently above 500ms whereas the request to the REST API is never above 200ms. *Why is it client library is so slow and are there ways I can optimize the requests?* I originally thought what was taking forever was the encoding into Base64, but when I timed it, the encoding took no more than 3ms. *That being said, would requesting the audioContent be in Base64 String make the request faster?* The TTS API documentation does not mention support of this for client side, so is it just not possible even?

Is there something wrong in how I'm using it? If I have to use the REST API for speed-sake, I also have the issue of needing to generate an authorization token in my program and constantly check and update when it expires. I've been manually using terminal to generate one then copy and paste it into my code. *Is there a library in Go where I can generate an access/authentication token for my Google Cloud Rest API?*

```
package main

import (
    b64 "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "context"

    texttospeech "cloud.google.com/go/texttospeech/apiv1"
    texttospeechpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/texttospeech/v1"
)

func audioFromClient(text string) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := texttospeech.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    req := &texttospeechpb.SynthesizeSpeechRequest{
        Input: &texttospeechpb.SynthesisInput{
            InputSource: &texttospeechpb.SynthesisInput_Text{Text: text},
        },
        Voice: &texttospeechpb.VoiceSelectionParams{LanguageCode: "en-US"},
        AudioConfig: &texttospeechpb.AudioConfig{
            AudioEncoding: texttospeechpb.AudioEncoding_MP3,
        },
    }

    resp, err := client.SynthesizeSpeech(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    audioContent := b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString((resp.AudioContent))
    _ = audioContent
    // GOT THE AUDIO IN BASE64
}

func audioFromRest(text string) {
    url := "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize"
    method := "POST"

    payload := strings.NewReader("{\n  \"input\": {\n    \"text\": \"Hello Gamers!\"\n  },\n  \"voice\": {\n    \"languageCode\": \"en-US\",\n    \"name\": \"en-US-Wavenet-A\",\n    \"ssmlGender\": \"MALE\"\n  },\n  \"audioConfig\": {\n    \"audioEncoding\": \"MP3\"\n  }\n}")

    client := &http.Client{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ********* ACCESS TOKEN *******")
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    res, err := client.Do(req)

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    _ = body
    // GOT THE AUDIO IN BASE64
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    audioFromClient("This a test!")
    fmt.Printf("[CLIENT LIBRARY took %.0fms]\n", float64(time.Since(start))/1e6)

    start = time.Now()
    audioFromRest("This a test!")
    fmt.Printf("[REST API took %.0fms]\n", float64(time.Since(start))/1e6)
}
```

Comment: Do you observe the same latency spikes using `texttospeech` package from [cloud.google.com/go/texttospeech/apiv1](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/texttospeech/apiv1)?